# How to calculate number of rows per group in pandas dataframe and add it to original data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

I have dataframe df like below

```
ID   COMMODITY_CODE   DELIVERY_TYPE  DAY   Window_start  case_qty     deliveries. 
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0    15:00                 15756.75    7.75
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0    18:00                 15787.75    5.75
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0    21:00                 10989.75    4.75
6042.0      SCGR        Live         2.0    15:00                 21025.25    9.00
6042.0      SCGR        Live         2.0    18:00                 16041.75    5.75
```

**I want below output** where i am grouping by ID, COMMODITY_CODE, DELIVERY_TYPE, DAY and Calculate window_count like below

```
ID   COMMODITY_CODE  DELIVERY_TYPE  DAY   Window_start  window_count   case_qty   deliveries
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0    15:00          3             15756.75     7.75
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0    18:00          3            15787.75      5.75
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0    21:00          3            10989.75      4.75
6042.0      SCGR        Live         2.0    15:00          2             21025.25     9.00
6042.0      SCGR        Live         2.0    18:00          2             16041.75     5.75
```

I tried below code by agg.

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','CHAMBER_TYPE','COMMODITY_CODE','DELIVERY_TYPE','DAY'],as_index=False)\
                     .agg(window_count=("DAY", "count"))
```

Even though ,it calculates the number of windows per ID,COMMODITY_CODE,DELIVERY_TYPE,DAY groups, it removes the older columns i.e. Window_start, case_qty, deliveries

i.e i get below output which is not desired

```
ID   COMMODITY_CODE  DELIVERY_TYPE  DAY   window_count 
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0               3             
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0               3            
6042.0      SCGR        Live         1.0               3            
6042.0      SCGR        Live         2.0               2             
6042.0      SCGR        Live         2.0               2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a `transform`:

```
df['window_count'] = df.groupby(['ID','CHAMBER_TYPE','COMMODITY_CODE','DELIVERY_TYPE','DAY'])['ID'].transform('size')
```

By the way, there is no `'CHAMBER_TYPE'` columns in your sample data.

Comment: You need to add the column before transform:

`df['window_count'] = df.groupby(['ID','COMMODITY_CODE','DELIVERY_TYPE','DAY']).DAY.transform('size')`